# Is django model field lookup_type 'contains' case-sensitive or insensitive..?

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-database, django-model-field

As per documentation 'contains' field lookup is case-sensitive and 'icontains' is case-Insensitive, but I don't see any difference while i'm querying it.

```
>>> from users.models import SnetUser
>>> SnetUser.objects.get(email__contains='Satti')
<SnetUser: satti>
>>> SnetUser.objects.get(email__contains='satti')
<SnetUser: satti>
>>> obj = SnetUser.objects.get(email__contains='satti')
>>> obj.email
'satti@gmail.com'
```

Both are resulting same.

Note: I'm using django's SQLite DB locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This case is written in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#contains).

`contains` field lookup is being converted to `LIKE` clause and in SQLite it is **case-insensitive**.

In case you want to make `LIKE` clause to work **case-sensitively**, you need to use the following `PRAGMA`:

`PRAGMA case_sensitive_like = true;`

```
>>> from django.db import connection

>>> with connection.cursor() as cursor:
...     cursor.execute('PRAGMA case_sensitive_like = true;')

>>> SnetUser.objects.get(email__contains='Satti')
<QuerySet []>
```